# UrlFetchApp doGet not called and return html with "Meet Google Drive"

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, urlfetch

I must be losing my mind as suddenly I can't get a simple web app to work.
When I use the URL generated in the browser everything works fine. When I run the script the result is HTML content with Meet Google Drive.

Here is the code:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('blabla').setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);  
}

function client() {
  var url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby2NVrhG0O5fE6gTgage2QPYH3UJ2s23AJDLnB9YL69uyDFlmM/exec';
  Logger.log(url);
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(result);
}
```

Both `doGet` and the `client` functions are at the same file which was never a problem. A version was saved and the app deployed as anyone accessing the app and run as user accessing the app. `result.getContentText()` returns the same html output. `result.getResponseCode()` returns `200` which supposed to be successful however I can't see the `doGet` being called.

Comment: How is the `client()` function being called?  Is the `client()` function referring to the same Apps Script file that it is in?  In other words, is the Apps Script making a `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` to itself?

Comment: Either in the same script (calling itself) or from a separate script I am getting the same result.

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
When you deploy the WebApp, make sure the authorizations are set to "Anyone, including Anonymous"!

Comment: In that case, I can only choose to Execute the app as Me (...), right?