# Send email from a Google Script with another 'From' address

Tags: google-apps-script

My Sheet-bound script is sending an email using MailApp.sendEmail.

The emails are always sent 'from' my own Gmail account. This project is for a customer, and I need his email to be the 'from' on these emails.

Reading similar questions I learn that the I only have flexibility in changing the name and replyTo address, using the advanced options of MailApp.sendEmail. However, the email address is still mine and Google doesn't offer any control over that.

I'm not familiar enough with all of the Google services and options to find the best way to do this. My customer does have a Google Apps for Business, but I don't.

Can I somehow create the email-sending function as a standalone script under his account, and somehow call it from the project under my account?
Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emails are always sent from the account of the user that executes the script. In case the email is sent by a triggered function (installable triggers are the only ones that are able to send emails since it requires explicit authorization) then the email is sent from the account of the user that created the trigger (and authorized it).
In your case, it seems that the easier solution would be to ask your customer to execute the script himself and initiate all the triggers himself too.
If that should not be possible then you could indeed use a standalone script that would work as a kind of proxy, ie it would receive a request to send a message and actually send it from the customer account while returning an acknowledgement to your script.
But that's a bit tricky... the first solution is more elegant.

---

### Edit :

I found the idea of sending emails through an independent script funny so I gave it a quick try and it seems to do the job pretty easily... test code below (this code should be deployed as a standalone app from your customer account) :

```
function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log('e = e'+JSON.stringify(e));
  if(e.parameter.recipient==null){return ContentService.createTextOutput("error, wrong request "+JSON.stringify(e)+"\n\n"+e.parameter.recipient+"\n\n"+e.parameter.subject+"\n\n"+e.parameter.body).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT)};
  try{
    MailApp.sendEmail(e.parameter.recipient, e.parameter.subject, e.parameter.body)
  }catch(err){
    return ContentService.createTextOutput('error : '+err).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('mail successfully sent').setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
}
```

note : the code below goes in your spreadsheet script, the doGet above is an standalone app running from your customer account.

```
function sendMail(recipient,subject,body){
  var sent = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://script.google.com/macros/s/---------------S381kO1Kqv61E/exec?recipient="+recipient+"&subject="+subject+"&body="+body);
  Logger.log(sent);
}

function test(){
  sendMail('recipient@gmail.com','test message','hello world')
}
```

I was able to send messages from my gmail account while being logged as a different user. (the url above is intentionally truncated, I don't want anyone to send email from my account ;-)

Comment: Thanks Serge. I'll try that. The doGet function is a standalone function at the customer's account, and the other functions are from my sheets-bound script. Correct? Can I also add "cc", "Bcc" and attachment (use the advanced options of sendEmail)? What does the truncated ID represent?

Comment: correct indeed;) - the cc and bcc options are not an issue but the attachment is not so easy. maybe you should try the implementation and start a new thread on the specific attachment issue. The truncated ID is actually a part of the url that provides access to the standalone webapp. You get this url when you deploy the doGet() script (use the icon with a cloud in the script editor and follow the instructions)

Comment: not working for me. Email is not sent. the 'sent' variable returned from UrlFetchApp seem to contain the html of Google's Drive home page or something. I did use the webb app URL of my deployed web app. Tried with two different accounts. How do I access the doGet logger console? Any ideas?

Comment: When sending the URL from a browser it works fine. I seem to suffer the same issue as reported here, but no resolution is available http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29432930/urlfetchapp-doget-not-called-and-return-html-with-meet-google-drive

Comment: how do you call the app ? did you deploy it with anonymous access ?

Comment: you can add a security check to the app by adding a parameter that is checked before accepting the  send request, some kind of password to prevent the app being used by anyone... I could update the code if you want.

Comment: indeed, it was the anonymous authorization. Works perfectly now, including cc and bcc which I've added. Also I took your suggestion and implemented a password check! Now - to get the attachment working! Some hints from your side before I try?

Comment: OK, I got everything to work, including attachment! I passed the (Google Drive) fileID as a parameter, made sure it is stored in a public folder with public authorizations, and added this: var file = DriveApp.getFileById(e.parameter.attach); and to the advanced options of the sendEmail function, I added: attachments:[file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]

Comment: @Sergeinsas Thanks for the code it works perfect when I pass the body of the message. But if I want to use the HTML Body , it soesn't send that. Is there a way we can pass the HTML body to send emails?

Comment: @MorSagmon: related to the issue with "the html of Google's Drive home page or something", how did you solve the problem?

Comment: @HoangTrinh Wow, been a while - I don't remember what I did. This project is long gone :)