# apps script mailapp object obscure mail from

Tags: google-apps-script

We are using MailApp to send email upon form submission. But we need to obscure who the message is sent by, i.e. the from field. The form will contain email addresses for a minor child and we need to keep that hidden until they get parental consent to reveal that information. Looking at parameters for the mailapp object I don't see a way we can set the 'from' address. Are there other options for generating an email from apps script?

Comment: There are many methods available for doing interesting things with email, and many sites that you can set up a whole host of things. You could go two ways with your question: either trying to find the specific way to solve the problem with the tool that you have selected... or maybe you should instead be asking "how can I restrict/hide/not give the email address of the sender, programmatically"?

Comment: Using the [`GmailApp` class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app) rather than `MailApp` offers more options for emails. If you're within a G Suite domain, you can obscure the sender with a generic `no-reply` address.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an if statement

So add a cell with parental consent.

Then add your mail in a function.

So set up your loop to run through the spread sheet

then your if statement such as

```
for (var i = 0; i < tsRows; i++) {
function checkAge() {
      if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("E" + i).getValue() == "No"){
Logger.log('Email not sent due to not having consent');
      }
      else{
    sendMail();
        }
    }
}
```

It would work. You just have to go along these lines :) You can do anything in app script pretty much!

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the answer above, I did some more searching. I didn't want to have the assent option as noted above.

I have not implemented it yet but per the google docs it is possible to convert a script to a 'web app' which runs under a different id.

This from the google doc describing the process:
To publish a script as a web app, follow these steps:

Save a new version of the script by selecting File > Manage Versions, then Save New Version.
Select Publish > Deploy as web app.
Under Project version, select the version you just saved. --- etc

That can be found at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

So, we will continue to perfect the script that fires on form submit. After we are feature complete, we will attempt to move it to a 'web app'.

Also I found after searching through stackoverflow more someone else asked the same question just a year ago. Bad for me not looking more.

The solution there is [Send email from a Google Script with another 'From' address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37503361/send-email-from-a-google-script-with-another-from-address)

the doGet function there uses mailapp and it is running as a different user.